# Sidekiq background job rollback when fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I want to know if a sidekiq background job will rollback its database if the job fail to finish? i.e machine died or something like that.

I'm using rails 4.2.1, sidekiq 4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidekiq doesn't really handle transactions, but Rails does. So if you have several statements you should wrap them in a transaction i.e.:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  User.update(amount: 100)
  Bank.update(amount: 0)
end
```

Then, if something goes wrong, these changes will be rolled back.